# Google accounts on my Galaxy S4

Tags: google-account, accounts

I would like to get rid of one of my Google accounts since I don't use it anymore. Currently I have both my Google accounts (gmail, Google+..) on my phone (Galaxy S4, had to link/transfer data from my old phone to my new) and all pictures and information and such gets saved to the old account I don't want to use anymore.

But I still have some important emails on the old account as well as some contacts and such which I would like to keep. **Can these be transferred to my other Google account which I wanna keep and have as my primary?**

What do I have to do in order to get rid of this old account I don't longer need without losing the data (pictures,  some emails, contacts) which are currently under that primary gmail/G+ account which I don't want anymore?

Otherwise,  is there an option to say "lock/disable" that old account so nothing gets send or saved to it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

**Important: Sync your old Google account data between your phone and Google before starting with the following instructions**.

You should log in to your old Google account, and then go to [**Google Takeout**](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout), where there are tools to export your account information to an archive (and even you'll be able to transfer all your Google+ circles to your new account).

[image: Google Takeout]

To move contacts and other info from the old account to the new one, follow the instructions from [this article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/58582).

Also you can go to [Data tools](https://www.google.com/settings/datatools) settings page, where you'll find how to delete your old account, in the section **Account management**. Good luck.

[image: Data tools]